# Nuxt.js + Algolia - search-box not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, algolia

I'm trying to implement Agolia in my Nuxt.js WebApp.
Following an example from the main Algolia docs https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/going-further/server-side-rendering/vue/#with-nuxt

Got me to the stage where I can see all the records:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73u9p.png)

But my search-box and pagination are not working. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong :(

I think the issue could be in my `plugins/index.js`

I've got:

```
import InstantSearch from 'vue-instantsearch';

export default {
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.use(InstantSearch);
    }
};
```

but I keep getting a message:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-instantsearch'. 'node_modules/vue-instantsearch/dist/vue-instantsearch.common.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm install @types/vue-instantsearch` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'vue-instantsearch';`
```

I don't understand why it's not working.

Is anybody able to help, please?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've spent almost the whole day and I actually made it to Algolia to work with Nuxt.
`plugins/index.js`  was not the issue

This function below was breaking everything apart :/

```
serverPrefetch() {
   return this.instantsearch.findResultsState(this).then(algoliaState => {
        this.$ssrContext.nuxt.algoliaState = algoliaState;
   });
},
```

Would somebody be able to explain what the function above is doing, please?
and also the one below. Because I cannot see any difference in functionality after removing those.

```
beforeMount() {
        const results = this.$nuxt.context.nuxtState.algoliaState || window.__NUXT__.algoliaState;
        this.instantsearch.hydrate(results);
},
```